# &nbsp; from http response is showing as 'undefined' in IE

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer, utf-8, angular8

In my API response body I'm having  . while this doen't create any issue in chrome/firefox. 
While rendering in IE 8, I'm seeing 'undefined' in my UI. 
I'm using Angular 8. and i'm already using utf-8 encoding in my index.html
`<meta charset="utf-8">`
Any idea what is causing the issue? Is it a Angular 8 IE bug?

Comment: It's not easy to understand your problem. Can you explain more and can you show us some code fragments?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official document](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support), Angular is supported in IE 9, 10, 11 versions. you are using the IE 8 that is not supported.

So I am not sure how your angular app is working in the IE 8 browser.

This can be a possible cause of this issue.

If you think that this is not the case then I suggest you try to provide the detailed information with some sample code and detailed steps for producing the issue and test the issue to check for the results.

Another thing I want to inform you that IE 8 is a too old version and it is out of support scope of Microsoft. I suggest you use the latest Microsoft browser or at least move to the IE 11 version.